# Why/Are unordered_map and unordered_set slower?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, stdmap, unordered-set, stdset

I was solving a simple problem of finding unique elements in an array. I used a `std::unordered_map` to count unique elements but it gave **Time Limit Exceeded** in one test case. Then I used a `std::unordered_set` with the same result.

PS: I used `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` because I read that these two are much much faster than `std::map` and `std::set` respectively.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, a;
    cin >> n;
    unordered_set<int> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        s.insert(a);
    }
    cout << s.size();
}
```

Test 7 exceeded the time limit.

#### My Question is:

If `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` are faster why did they give TLE?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: What are the bounds for n and a?

Comment: `std::unordered_map` and `utd::unordered_set` are not inherently faster. Nothing is just "magic speed" in programming. You have to know how and when to use what.

Comment: You could try to allocate memory first, this would probably increase your code speed

Comment: Does the code work within the given time limit if you use `std::set` instead of `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: In your example any container will be much faster than user input you are waiting.

Comment: @sepp2k i am getting Accepted by using set

Comment: @Aplet123 

1≤n≤2⋅10^5 
1≤a≤10^9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unordered_set<int>` is a node-based container, where each element is stored in separately allocated list node. The list node contains an `int` element and two list node pointers, which, on a 64-bit platform, makes each list node occupy 24 bytes due to alignment. There is also allocator overhead for each allocated chunk of memory (8 bytes for GNU libc), so that there is at least 28 bytes of overhead for each 4-byte `int` element.

`s.insert(a);` makes a memory allocation for each new element and that is what makes the code slow.

---

To solve this problem efficiently you can use a bitset indexed by the integers, e.g. `std::vector<bool>`. Set the bit to 1 for each read integer and then count the number of set bits. If the elements are signed, covert them to unsigned to make the bit index a non-negative number.

A working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<bool> bitset(1000000001); // a range is 1≤a≤10^9.

    for(int i = 0, a; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> a;
        bitset[static_cast<unsigned>(a)] = true;
    }
    std::cout << std::accumulate(bitset.begin(), bitset.end(), 0u) << '\n';
}
```

---

A version that passes that grader:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::bitset<1000000001> bitset; // a range is 1≤a≤10^9.
    unsigned unique = 0;
    for(int i = 0, a; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> a;
        if(!bitset.test(a)) {
            ++unique;
            bitset.set(a);
        }
    }
    std::cout << unique << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What if `a` is `INT_MAX`? This is only applicable if we know bounds on `a`.

Comment: You can create a bitset with 2^32 elements, it occupies 2^29 bytes, or 512MB.

Comment: What if `a` is -1? :D

Comment: I appreciate the example.

Comment: We could use `std::bitset` instead of vector here, since the size is constexpr.

Comment: @Ayxan `std::bitset` stores elements inline (not in dynamically allocated memory). `std::bitset` with 2^32 bits would take 512MB on the stack, which your platform may not support. For example, on Linux, the default maximum stack size is around 8MB.

Comment: This Code is giving Run time error (No Output).Whats the fix?

Comment: @DEVANSHMESSON It fails because it uses too much memory. Since the range of `a` is  (1≤a≤10^9), a fix is `std::vector<bool> bitset(1000000001);` (Uses 8 times less memory).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Can you expain this line:
static_cast<unsigned>(a)

Comment: @DEVANSHMESSON It cast `int` to `unsigned`, because vector indexes are non-negative. Since your inputs are non-negative numbers, the cast is not really needed, but it doesn't hurt either because it compiles to 0 instructions.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin so if i have the input -3 and next input is 3.
But static_cast<unsigned>(a) will convert -3 to 3 and this will be a problem because there will be two 3's and my answer will be wrong?

Comment: `-3` is going to be a large positive number when converted to `unsigned` in 2's-complement system (x86, ARM). This is why the original bitset size covered all `unsigned` values.

Comment: Thank you so much sir @MaximEgorushkin.You Helped a lot!

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin i submitted the code to the online judge its giving TLE for all test cases.Any reason for it?

Comment: @DEVANSHMESSON Post a link to the online judge and I will have a look.

Comment: Link - https://cses.fi/problemset/result/474865/ 
@MaximEgorushkin
But i think you not be able to see that result 
Its just showing TLE for all test cases thats it

Comment: @DEVANSHMESSON Added another version for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @MaximEgorushkin.All Test Cases Passed(AC).You're genius.I learned a new technique!

Comment: @DEVANSHMESSON That grader is a bit too strict, IMO.

Comment: Thats why i am practicing there.But i wanna ask why that previous code exceeded time limit? @MaximEgorushkin

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Can You solve this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048413/how-to-code-to-have-upper-bound-of-second-element-of-vector-pair-based-on-first

Answer (score 1):

`std::unordered_map` gives result in o(1) most of the time , not always . 
Coming to the TLE issue , there might be a possibility that constraints are more than 10^18 and in this case o(n) complexity will not work . Try o(log(n)) approach.

Comment: You mean O(1) instead of O(n)? O(n) insert is the worst case. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)

Answer (score 1):

The unordered containers are optimized for retrieving values, not for inserting them.

You could take a look at this comparison https://medium.com/@nonuruzun/stl-container-performance-3ec5a8fbc3be. There, you can see that the unordered containers have the O(N) worst case for inserting while the ordered ones have O(log(N))

But you can fix that by allocating memory first, so you will have less collisions.

Comment: How can i allocate memory first ?