# How to code to have upper bound of second element of vector pair based on first element of vector pair

Tags: c++

I have a sorted(according to `first.second` element)vector pair of following type :
`vector<pair<pair<int,int>,int>>p;`

My Comparator function to sort vector pair

```
bool sortbysec(pair<pair<int,int>,int>&a,pair<pair<int,int>,int>&b)
{
  if(a.first.second==b.first.second)return a.first.first<b.first.first;
  else return a.first.second<b.first.second;
}
```

I want upper bound of `p.first.second`element on the list of `p.first.first`elements.

For example -

```
    2 2 7
    1 3 4
    1 4 3
    4 5 8
    5 7 5
    4 8 6
    5 8 1
    6 8 9
    8 8 0
    8 9 2
```

In simple words, I want an upper bound of middle element of the vector pair.Searching the upper bound of that particular element should be done in list of first element of the vector pair.

For Example, upper bound of 3 in second row is 4 in the 4th row.

My question is :
I dont know how to code this thing. I have tried this syntax(incorrect):

```
auto it=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),make_pair(make_pair(2,2),7));
```

This is showing error.
I hope you understood the question.
Please anyone tell me a way how to code it properly so i get the desired results in c++ only.

Comment: I think you cant use all the search function because all of them are searching by key, and you need to search by value

Comment: Can you elaborate please @yaodav

Comment: please provide a [mcve], `std::lower_bound` requires the vector to be sorted with respect to the same comparator, and what bound to choose also depends on your comparator. Did you use the default `<` ?

Comment: @yaoday its a vector not a map, there are only values no keys. `lower_bound` can also be used for vectors

Comment: How about `std::tuple<int, int, int>` (or `std::array<int, 3>`) instead of `pair<pair<int,int>,int>`?

Comment: *"I have a sorted vector"* only with a custom comparer you should show.  (seems to be `second, first, third`). and also provide to `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: *"This is showing error"* which one?

Comment: now I understand your problem, the lower_bound function don't know how to compare your object - you need to to write your one comparator

Comment: @Jarod42 auto it=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),make_pair(make_pair(2,2),7));This is showing error

Comment: @yaodav thats what my question is.i am not able to code the comparator function

Comment: @idclev463035818 my vector is sorted according to first.second element of vector pair

Comment: how did you sort it? Did you use a custom comparator or the default `<` ? Please include a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: @idclev463035818 Please read the question again. i have added(just now) my custom comparator function which i used to sort the vector pair

Comment: Let me try to explain. I dont know c++ from memory. I know how to rtfm, I know how to write code, usually it has lots of errors, then I read the error message and fix the errors. To help you I would need to repeat this whole process that you already did. And to be plain honest I am too lazy to do that. On the other hand if you would include a [mcve] and the error message the question would be much easier to answer. The only thing I know for sure is that you need to use the same comparater for `lower_bound` as the one you used for sorting, but atm I have honestly no clue what your error is

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is the code and error - https://ideone.com/2ho6kj

Comment: you should include the code and the error in the question! The problem is not the line you posted. There is no syntax error. The only problem in that line is that you should use the same comparator as for sorting. The actual problem is `#define int long long int`. This is undefined behavior. You are lucky that you got a compiler error and not worse. Don't ever do that. If you want to declare a variable of type `long long int` then write `long long int x;` because when you write `int x;` you declare a variable of type `int` not of type `long long int` (unless you break the language)

Comment: @idclev463035818 , My error resolved by removing #define int  long long int . I want to ask will i able to solve my problem(my real question) by using same comparator which i used for sorting?

Comment: what is your "real" question? After removing that non-sense line your code compiles without errors